# Perimeter of a Segment

Tags: geometry

Hey I've got some last maths tests before my GCSE and one of the topics we need to revise is Perimeter of a Segment. I cant explicitly find a guide on how to do it so if anyone could tell me the general method for it with maybe an example question that would be much appreciated.

[image: A segment of a disk]

I did find this diagram and thought that maybe if you found the arc length and then found the side of the triangle which connects with the chord maybe you add them together to get perimeter? is that right or wrong

Comment: Perimeter of a segment? Is it not the length of the segment?

Comment: Well my revision list says perimeter so im not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a method

Find the total circumference and multiply this by $\frac{\theta}{2\pi}$ ( $\theta$ is in radians ) to get length of arc..Add the Line segment's length which bounds the arc...

If the length of Line segment binding the arc is not given and radius and central angle are given , you could use Law of Cosines

$$c=\sqrt{2r^2-2r^2\cos{\theta}}$$ $r$ is radius of circle
and $\theta$ is the angle subtended at centre.

So, yes , what you are saying about finding $perimeter$ is correct

Comment: Ah ok thanks for the answer.